# How fast is the naked-eye visible transition of a main sequence star to a giant?

Tags: sun, stars, stellar-evolution

I know the evolution of a main sequence star to a giant is a process that takes millions and millions of years, but how fast is the VISIBLE change? Basically, will our sun, for example, slowly grow to envelope the orbits of the inner planets, or will there be a sudden inflation of that star to a new much greater volume on a timescale of seconds or minutes or hours etc.?

Comment: It will (and is) gradually increase to a greater volume over a span of millions of years. This post is more suitable for astronomy.SE than phys.SE.